# Dynamically build response entity json

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have rest end point which has set of attributes. The user can select attributes need by them. As per the user selection i need to generate the reports.

I use the restTemplate to get the data from end point and populate my response object.

Is there a way I can generate the response object dynamically.

Like if user select

A
B
C 
D

```
      restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, response.class);
```

In this case my response object should look like

```
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

public class Response {

```
@JsonProperty("A")
public String A;

@JsonProperty("B")
public String B;

@JsonProperty("C")
public Integer c;

@JsonProperty("D")
public String D;

}
```

Currently I am statically define the response class, can we dynamically define the response class as per the attributes required by user. please let me know how it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", "hello");
map.put("B", 2);
String s = objectMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(map);
System.out.println("s = " + s);
```

Output is

```
s = {"A":"hello","B":2}
```

Comment: I want the other way, I have a json with 100 attributes and I want to select the attributes as requested by user only may be 5 out of 100, the selected 5 will vary.

Comment: Then parse it to a Map<String, Object>, and iterate over the entries of the map.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be the creation of a dynamic filter.

Jackson has a built-in filter mechanism which works on simple property filtering. 
The default implementation is pretty basic. It allows filtering on simple properties.

The idea would be to dynamically create the string array of properties to filter (include and exclude) with the input request and build the response accordingly.

If you want a more sofisticated filter you could try an addon library I just pushed on github.

Even if you dont need this kind of advanced filtering i think the `Usage` part of my readme can give you already some hints about the filtering approach.

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter